# Python - If column name contains a specific string then change the values in that column otherwise the values remain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write some code which looks at the column names and sets the column value to 0 if that column name contains a specific string. I have a dataset with columns similar to this:

```
date apples_sold bananas_sold pineapples_sold orange_sold
```

I want to update any columns with the string "apple" to make every row 0 for that column. If the column doesn't contain "apple" then the value should remain.

I tried looping through the column names but am unsure the syntax as I don't want to hardcode the specific column names.

Answer (score 3):

Try `loc` update with `.str.contains`:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('apple')] = 0
```

Comment: That's amazing. I wish I asked this before spending hours on this. So eloquent, yet simple. Thank you!